# How to deploy an angular 6 app with asp.net web api on a server like godaddy

Tags: asp.net-web-api, deployment, angular6

I have an angular project and a asp.net mvc web api project in the same solution. Now, I want to deploy them both on my godaddy server. I have searched all over the internet but couldn't find a solution.

I can deploy the dist folder of my angular app it is working fine but I can get to make my api work. Can someone suggest something on this?